# A grid and a menu walked into a program

Tags: java, beginner, matrix

A program that creates a grid 10x10 and assigns a random number in each tile. It then asks you if you want to:

- create a new grid
- view the current one
- count how many of each number there are in the grid
- sum the rows
- sum the columns
- exit the program

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tenxten {
    static int numberRows = 10;
    static int numberColumns = 10;
    static int [][] grid = new int [numberColumns][numberRows];

    private static int randomInt(int from, int to) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(to - from + 1) + from;
    }

    private static void amountOfSpecificNumbers() {
        int[] numbers = new int[numberColumns * numberRows];
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                    if (grid[y][x] == i) {
                        numbers[i] += i;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" " + numbers[i] / i + " " + i + "s" );
        }
    }

    private static void sumOfColumns() {
        int sumOfColumns[] = new int[numberColumns];
        for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < numberRows; y++) {
                sumOfColumns[y] += grid[x][y];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sumOfColumns));
    }

    private static void sumOfRows() {
        int sumOfRows[] = new int[numberColumns];
        for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < numberRows; y++) {
                sumOfRows[x] += grid[x][y];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sumOfRows));
    }

    private static void newField() {
        for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < numberRows; y++) {
                int randomNumber = (randomInt(1, 10));
                grid[x][y] = randomNumber;
                if (randomNumber < 10) {
                    System.out.print(" " + randomNumber + " ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(randomNumber + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void showField() {
        for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < numberRows; y++) {
                if (grid[x][y] < 10) {
                    System.out.print(" " + grid[x][y] + " ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(grid[x][y] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static int readInt(Scanner scanner){
        int choice = 0;
        while(choice > 6 || choice < 1) {
            System.out.println("Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6");
            while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("That's not even a number");
                System.out.println("Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6");
                scanner.next();
            }
            choice = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        return choice;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        newField();
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
            System.out.println("1. Get a new field");
            System.out.println("2. Show current field");
            System.out.println("3. Count the numbers in the current field");
            System.out.println("4. Sum all rows");
            System.out.println("5. Sum all columns");
            System.out.println("6. Exit program");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            int choice = readInt(scanner);

            if (choice == 1){
                newField();
            } else if (choice == 2){
                showField();
            } else if (choice == 3){
                amountOfSpecificNumbers();
            } else if (choice == 4){
                sumOfRows();
            } else if (choice == 5){
                sumOfColumns();
            }else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
public class tenxten {
```

Java classes should start with a capital letter, and according to Java conventions should be named with something called "PascalCase". A name like `TenXTen` would adhere to that convention.

---

```
static int numberRows = 10;
static int numberColumns = 10;
```

These are effectively used as constants (they do not change). Therefore they can be:

```
private static final int NUMBER_ROWS = 10;
private static final int NUMBER_COLUMNS = 10;
```

(Constants are by convention named with ALL_CAPS_AND_UNDERLINES)

---

```
static int [][] grid = new int [numberColumns][numberRows];
```

At one place you write `grid[y][x]` and in others `grid[x][y]`

Luckily for you, it has the same dimensions so you won't notice, but should it be the following?

```
static int [][] grid = new int [numberRows][numberColumns];
```

---

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

You are currently creating one `Random` each time you are generating a number. `Random` objects are meant to be re-used (for "better randomization" - I know it sounds fuzzy but trust me on this one).

---

```
 for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
```

and

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
```

Use the constants for the upper bound for `x` and `y` here.

---

`newField` has some duplication from `showField`. It might be better remove the output from `newField` and call the methods like this:

```
newField();
showField();
```

---

I believe your `readInt` method can be rewritten using `do-while`,

```
int choice;
do {
    System.out.println("Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6");
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That's not even a number");
        System.out.println("Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6");
        scanner.next();
    }
    choice = scanner.nextInt();
}
while (choice > 6 || choice < 1);
return choice;
```

---

Your `amountOfSpecificNumbers()` method can be simplified in a couple of ways:

- use `numbers[i]++;` instead of `numbers[i] += i;` and you won't have to divide by `i` in the output.
- don't use the outer loop, use a loop after the nested loop instead
- `int[] numbers` doesn't need to be that big, it is currently 100 in size but only needs to be 10.

  ```
  private static void amountOfSpecificNumbers() {
      int[] numbers = new int[10];
      for (int y = 0; y < NUMBER_ROWS; y++) {
          for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_COLUMNS; x++) {
              int value = grid[y][x];
              numbers[value]++;
          }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(" " + numbers[i] + " " + i + "s" );
      }
  }
  ```

---

A little nitpick: Sometimes you are writing

```
int[] array
```

and sometimes

```
int array[]
```

while both works in Java, I would recommend sticking to one (I personally prefer `int[] array`)

---

Finally, imagine if you would have the requirement to handle more than one `TenXTen` grid at a time. Your program would really *need* `TenXTen` as an independent class in that case. (Currently, it doesn't need it, but it would be useful).

Many of your methods are returning `void` and doing the output inside the method. It is a better idea to return the values required for the output, and do the output outside the method itself.

Imagine a <s>`TenXTen` grid</s> ...who said it has to be 10 x 10 at all times? Consider the name `NumberGrid`... anyway, consider a class with these methods:

- `void generate()`
- `int[] amountOfSpecificNumbers()`
- `int[] sumOfColumns()`
- `int[] sumOfRows()`
- `void showField()`

Then you would be able to use this methods for example like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberGrid grid = new NumberGrid(20, 10);
    grid.showField();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grid.sumOfColumns()));
    grid.generate();
}
```

etc... you might want to read up on [Java Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) for that.

Answer (score 16):

#### Don't store data in static fields

The biggest issue in this program is that all the data is stored in `static` fields.
It would make sense to make everything non-static except the main method,
so that you can have multiple instances.

#### No need for multiple `Random` instances

> ```
> private static int randomInt(int from, int to) {
>     Random rand = new Random();
>     return rand.nextInt(to - from + 1) + from;
> }
> ```

It's inefficient and completely unnecessary to generate a new instance of `Random` every time you want to generate a new int.
It would be better to create a single `Random` instance and reuse that.

#### Simplify `if-else` chain with a `switch`

Instead of these chained else-ifs:

> ```
> if (choice == 1){
>     newField();
> } else if (choice == 2){
>     showField();
> } else if (choice == 3){
> // ...
> ```

It's better to use a `switch`:

```
switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        newField();
        break;
    case 2:
        showField();
        break;
    // ... 
}
```

#### Use consistent dimension constants

The `grid` is initialized using `numberColumns` and `numberRows` as the dimensions:

> ```
> static int[][] grid = new int[numberColumns][numberRows];
> ```

But then, everywhere else in the code, 
you iterate using the hardcoded number 10 as the index bound
It would be better to reuse the `numberColumns` and `numberRows` in those iterations.
And, of course, since these are constants, 
the common convention is name them with ALL CAP letters.

#### Avoid code duplication

This `readInt` method has a duplicate string in it,
and it wastes an evaluation of `choice` the first time.

> ```
> private static int readInt(Scanner scanner){
>     int choice = 0;
>     while(choice > 6 || choice < 1) {
>         System.out.println("Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6");
>         while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
>             System.out.println("That's not even a number");
>             System.out.println("Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6");
>             scanner.next();
>         }
>         choice = scanner.nextInt();
>     }
>     return choice;
> }
> ```

It would be better to eliminate the duplication and to convert to a do-while loop:

```
private static int readInt(Scanner scanner) {
    String prompt = "Please enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6";
    int choice;
    do {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("That's not even a number");
            System.out.println(prompt);
            scanner.next();
        }
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
    } while (choice > 6 || choice < 1);
    return choice;
}
```

You can do even better and simplify without a loop, using an appropriate pattern in `scanner.hasNext`:

```
private static int readInt(Scanner scanner) {
    String prompt = "Please enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6";
    System.out.println(prompt);
    while (!scanner.hasNext("[1-6]")) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        scanner.next();
    }
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
```