# The grid looked at the menu and said "Something with class, please"

Tags: java, beginner, classes, matrix

This is a follow up on my previous question:

[A grid and a menu walked into a program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/78014/32061)

- I integrated classes into the mix.
- The program now asks how big you want the grid to be.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


class NumberGrid {
    private static final int RANDOM_NUMBER = 10;
    static Random rand = new Random();
    public int numberColumns;
    public int numberRows;
    int [][] grid;
    public NumberGrid (int chosenNumberRows,int chosenNumberColumns ){
        numberColumns = chosenNumberColumns;
        numberRows = chosenNumberRows;
        grid = new int [numberRows][numberColumns];
    }

    private static int randomInt(int from, int to) {
        return rand.nextInt(to - from + 1) + from;
    }

    public void amountOfSpecificNumbers() {
        int[] numbers = new int[11];
        for (int y = 0; y < numberRows; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
                int value = grid[y][x];
                numbers[value]++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" " + numbers[i] + " " + i + "s" );
        }
    }

    public void sumOfColumns() {
        int sumOfColumns[] = new int[numberColumns];
        for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < numberRows; y++) {
                sumOfColumns[x] += grid[y][x];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sumOfColumns));
    }

    public void sumOfRows() {
        int sumOfRows[] = new int[numberRows];
        for (int y = 0; y < numberRows; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
                sumOfRows[y] += grid[y][x];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sumOfRows));
    }

    public void newField() {
        for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < numberRows; y++) {
                int randomNumber = (randomInt(1, RANDOM_NUMBER));
                grid[y][x] = randomNumber;
            }
        }
    }

    public void showField() {
        for (int y = 0; y < numberRows; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
                if (grid[y][x] < 10) {
                    System.out.print(" " + grid[y][x] + " ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(grid[y][x] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int readInt(Scanner scanner){
        String prompt = ("Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6");
        System.out.println(prompt);
        while(!scanner.hasNext("[1-6]")) {
            System.out.println(prompt);
            scanner.next();
        }
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }

}

class GridColumns {
    public static int readInt(Scanner scanner){
        String prompt = ("Pleas enter the number of columns you want");
        System.out.println(prompt);
        while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) {

            System.out.println("That's not a number");
            System.out.println(prompt);
            scanner.next();
        }
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}

class GridRows{
    public static int readInt(Scanner scanner){
        String prompt = ("Pleas enter the number of rows you want");
        System.out.println(prompt);
        while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) {

            System.out.println("That's not a number");
            System.out.println(prompt);
            scanner.next();
        }
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}

public class TenXTen {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberGrid numberGrid = new NumberGrid(GridRows.readInt(scanner),GridColumns.readInt(scanner));

        numberGrid.newField();
        numberGrid.showField();
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
            System.out.println("1. Get a new field");
            System.out.println("2. Show current field");
            System.out.println("3. Count the numbers in the current field");
            System.out.println("4. Sum all rows");
            System.out.println("5. Sum all columns");
            System.out.println("6. Exit program");

            int choice = numberGrid.readInt(scanner);

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    numberGrid.newField();
                    numberGrid.showField();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numberGrid.showField();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numberGrid.amountOfSpecificNumbers();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numberGrid.sumOfRows();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numberGrid.sumOfColumns();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok this is it. I'm taking a note right here, in prevision of the "Best of Code Review 2015 - Best Title Category" ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug bonus points for having the author name it themselves, rather than us renaming the question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Field Visibility

Restrict field visibility as much as possible. Use `private final` wherever you can (the compiler will let you know if you can't).

---

#### Using `this.` in constructor

In your constructor, you can use `this.` to assign your fields. This will allow you to use the same parameter names as field names. For example:

```
public NumberGrid(int numberRows, int numberColumns) {
    this.numberColumns = numberColumns;
    this.numberRows = numberRows;
    this.grid = new int[numberRows][numberColumns];
}
```

---

#### Use your constants

In `amountOfSpecificNumbers()`:

```
int[] numbers = new int[11];
```

make that

```
int[] numbers = new int[RANDOM_NUMBER + 1];
```

---

#### Unnecessary parenthesis

You are using an unnecessary extra set of parenthesis on these lines:

```
int randomNumber = (randomInt(1, RANDOM_NUMBER));
String prompt = ("Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6");
String prompt = ("Pleas enter the number of columns you want");
```

Those can become:

```
int randomNumber = randomInt(1, RANDOM_NUMBER);
String prompt = "Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6";
String prompt = "Pleas enter the number of columns you want";
```

---

#### Scattered `readInt` methods

There is currently `NumberGrid.readInt`, `GridColumns.readInt`, and `GridRows.readInt`.

- The `NumberGrid.readInt` method is not related to `NumberGrid` directly, it is more a method used to control the program flow. I would put this method in the `TenXTen` class. I would name this method `readMenuChoice`
- `GridColumns.readInt` and `GridRows.readInt` does not need to be inside their own classes. They also belong in the `TenXTen` class. I would name these methods as `readColumnsCount` and `readRowsCount` (or use @Pimgd's suggestion and merge those two methods into one - but still put them as `static` methods inside `TenXTen`).

Answer (score 25):

```
private static final int RANDOM_NUMBER = 10;
```

[image: XKCD random number]

Everyone knows the true random number is 4.

Less jokingly, what's the `RANDOM_NUMBER` for? Consider adding comments to explain the purpose of your variables... or better yet renaming them (to `RANDOM_GRIDVALUE_MAX`, perhaps).

```
static Random rand = new Random();
public int numberColumns;
public int numberRows;
int [][] grid;
```

You're missing visibility modifiers on some of your variables. Is this intentional?

Additionally, `rand` could be `final`, because it's only set once and then never set again. Perhaps (hint: there are) some of the other variables could be `final` too.

---

```
public NumberGrid (int chosenNumberRows,int chosenNumberColumns ){

private static int randomInt(int from, int to) {
```

Check your IDE for consistent syntax formatting. As an example, for Eclipse:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
>
> Or, in the main menu > Source > Format

---

```
String prompt = ("Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6");
```

Typo ("Pleas" -> "Please").

---

```
public void showField() {
    for (int y = 0; y < numberRows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
            if (grid[y][x] < 10) {
                System.out.print(" " + grid[y][x] + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(grid[y][x] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You're printing SPACE + cell + SPACE if it's less than 10, or cell + SPACE if it isn't.

This was rather unclear to me... until I realized it's for padding.

I recommend moving the if statement to a separate function such as `printNumberSpacePadded(int number, int toLength)`.

---

```
class GridColumns {
    public static int readInt(Scanner scanner){
        String prompt = ("Pleas enter the number of columns you want");
        System.out.println(prompt);
        while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) {

            System.out.println("That's not a number");
            System.out.println(prompt);
            scanner.next();
        }
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}

class GridRows{
    public static int readInt(Scanner scanner){
        String prompt = ("Pleas enter the number of rows you want");
        System.out.println(prompt);
        while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) {

            System.out.println("That's not a number");
            System.out.println(prompt);
            scanner.next();
        }
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Hello duplication.

Meet `readInt`:

```
public static int readInt(Scanner scanner, String inputMessage, String errorMessage) {
    System.out.println(inputMessage);
    while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println(errorMessage);
        System.out.println(inputMessage);
        scanner.next();
    }
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Stick it somewhere, maybe in a class `ScannerUtils` or `InputHandler` (the latter one, I would make responsible of all input).

But wait, it doesn't support this version:

```
public static int readInt(Scanner scanner){
    String prompt = ("Pleas enter number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6");
    System.out.println(prompt);
    while(!scanner.hasNext("[1-6]")) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        scanner.next();
    }
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
```

For that, simply add a `String validInputPattern` or something like that.

---

I don't think you understood classes yet. Or maybe you did, but only in a functional sense.

You've got classes that contain no variables and don't have any non-static methods. Because of that, they're little more than utility boxes...

`NumberGrid` is good, though.

---

Lastly... That menu at the end, I would rewrite it to use lambda's and some other clever trickery so that I can say something like this:

```
addMenuItem("Show current field", () -> numberGrid.showField());
```

This would then add the "2" in front of it on it's own.

Perhaps it's a bad idea, but I think it's worth a try. I don't like how `case 5:` means `numberGrid.sumOfColumns()` because there's a double duplication here...

`System.out.println("5. Sum all columns");` the 5 duplicates `case 5:`, and `System.out.println("5. Sum all columns");` the "Sum all columns" duplicates `numberGrid.sumOfColumns();`. Now this form of duplication isn't *bad*, it's just that as you add lines between the menu and the actions, it becomes harder to verify that the code is actually working as intended.